# How to create and perform data manipulations with Neo4j database in PHP

Tags: php, neo4j

I am working with Neo4j database with PHP at https://github.com/neo4j-php/neo4j-php-client.

I have successfully installed the projects via Composer and have my neo4j database server running locally. I have also tested the sample applications.

**sample.php**

```
<?php

require ('vendor/autoload.php');
$client = Laudis\Neo4j\ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addHttpConnection('backup', 'http://neo4j:foodisgood56@localhost')
    ->addBoltConnection('default', 'bolt://neo4j:foodisgood56@localhost')
    ->setDefaultConnection('default')
    ->build();


foreach ($client->run('UNWIND range(1, 9) as x RETURN x') as $item) {
    echo $item->get('x');
}


?>
```

and it echos  **123456789** which suggests that my local neo4j database server is working fine.

**Here are my questions**

**1.) How create table Eg Table users_table via neo4js in PHP**

something like

`create table users_table(id int primary key auto_increment, fullname varchar(30), password varchar(30), email varchar(30));`

**2.) How to inserts, updates, select and delete example via php for neo4js**

How can I achieve equivalents of this php PDO in Neo4j database

**For insert**

```
$statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users_table
(password,fullname,email)
 values
(:password,:fullname,:email)');

$statement->execute(array( 
':password' => 'my pass',
':fullname' => 'Nkem C',
':email' => 'testing@gmail.com'));
```

**For Update**

```
$update = $db->prepare('UPDATE users_table set password=:password, fullname=:fullname where email=:email');

$update->execute(array( 
':password' => 'my pass1',
':fullname' => 'Nkem C1',
':email' => 'testing@gmail.com'));
```

**For Delete**

```
$del1 = $db->prepare('DELETE from users_table  where email=:email');

$del1->execute(array( 
':email' => 'testing@gmail.com'));



// delete all
$del2 = $db->prepare('DELETE from users_table');
$del2->execute(array());
```

**For Select**

```
$query1 = $db->prepare('SELECT * from users_table  where email=:email and password=:password');

$query1->execute(array( 
':email' => 'testing@gmail.com',
':password' => 'my pass'
));



// select all
$query2 = $db->prepare('SELECT * from users_table');
$query2->execute(array());
```

Comment: Hi Nancy, first of all, Neo4j doesn't have tables. I suggest you to take a look at the core concepts of Neo4j. Then you can take a look at Cypher https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher/ that is the language used to query Neo4j. For PHP you can just use $client->run and write the query you need as the parameter.

Comment: Thanks. i understand it now